# Removing Dupes in joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, duplicates

Nothing I've tried removes dupes from table 1

Here is a basic join of my tables

```
SELECT t1.ORDERNUM,
    t1.TOTALAMT,
    t2.refrence,
    t2.DEBITAMT
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2
       ON t1.ORDERNUM = t2.REFRENCE
WHERE t2.REFRENCE = 'PO_309-20142153'
```

I end up with

```
ORDERNUM    TOTALAMT    refrence                    DEBITAMT
309-20142153    1420.920000 PO_309-20142153_                0.00000
309-20142153    1420.920000 PO_309-20142153_                62.15000
309-20142153    1420.920000 PO_309-20142153_                86.85000
309-20142153    1420.920000 PO_309-20142153_                129.56000
309-20142153    1420.920000 PO_309-20142153_                201.97000
309-20142153    1420.920000 PO_309-20142153_                376.80000
309-20142153    1420.920000 PO_309-20142153_                563.59000
```

^^^^^^^^^^^ How do I remove these dupes?

Expected first two records:

| ORDERNUM | TOTALAMT | refrence | DEBITAMT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 309-20142153 | 1420.920000 | PO_309-20142153_ | 0.00000 |
| PO_309-20142153_ | 62.15000 | PO_309-20142153_ | 86.85000 |

I have tried the joins, a subquery, group bys.  I either get dupes for table1 or all nulls.

I'm hoping to remove the duplicates in table 1 so I can add it to an SSRS report cleanly. and sum them up without having 2 bazillion in the 2nd column

I am running SQL Server

Comment: there are no duplicates as every DEBITAMT is unique, what exactly you try to achieve

Comment: Duplicates in joins typically means you don't understand your data, because otherwise the solution is usually obvious.

Comment: What does duplicate mean to you? Should OrderNum to be unique in the result? If OrderNum is not unique in Table1, what is the accurate way to remove the duplicates, leaving syntax aside? Want to get any record, just one single per OrderNum? Is there a date column you can use to get the latest? Do you want to average/max/min TOTALAMT by OrderNum? There are nigh infinite ways to dedup a result, but the correct thing depends on your requirement. If orderNum is unique in table 1, your duplicates are in Table2 on refrence. In which case a simple aggregate on  orderNum and TotalAmount is fine.

Comment: Additionally, I'm not sure if these are artifacts of foreign keys, but `309-20142153` != `PO_309-20142153_`

Comment: We need a [mre] with sample data, desired results and one of your attempts.

Comment: Sorry, it made sense when I posted, but now I see I didn't explain it will enough.  The result I'm looking for is:
ORDERNUM    TOTALAMT    refrence                    DEBITAMT
309-20142153    1420.920000 PO_309-20142153_                0.00000
                                                 PO_309-20142153_                62.15000
                                                 PO_309-20142153_                86.85000

   and so on...
I hope this is making more sense.  I can't format the table in comments

Comment: @Jack'sDad No worries, there is a learning curve to asking questions here. I moved your expected result in to the question body. Can you make sure that is correct, and if so, use that as a template and fill out the rest, with some language on why it will look the way you want it to.

Comment: And how is the final column calculated? Just a sum of all values in that column?

Comment: to oversimplify, I want only the 1st instance of 309-20142153    1420.920000
Then I wasnt the rest not to show up.

Comment: i think you'd better do this in the report. this is not really how you're supposed to fetch data, you have subreports and main reports which display sections

Comment: You still haven't clarified what value of DEBITAMT you want to see - the first value? If so why are you even joining at all? We need to see some sample raw (starting) data and understand the logic you are using to select "1" row. Because as it stands its not clear.

Answer (score 1):

Your fail with group by was due to the fact that you grouped by the last column as well which differs from line to line. Do it like this:

```
SELECT t1.ORDERNUM,
    t1.TOTALAMT,
    t2.refrence,
    SUM(t2.DEBITAMT) AS DEBITAMT
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2
       ON t1.ORDERNUM = t2.REFRENCE
WHERE t2.REFRENCE = 'PO_309-20142153'
GROUP BY t.ORDERNUM, t1.TOTALAMT, t2.refrence
```